# using YUI3 tabview in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, yui3

i try to use the YUI3 tabview widget in zend framework.

i use the Yahoo CDN to load all the modules, every things is fine, i got the combo with `tabview.css` inside except that i can't download the image file that is used in the `tabview.css`.the same code works fine in a plain html file and the image is right there. why this is happening?

here is a test page http://www.ceshi.anpingsiwang.info, the tabview.css is in the css combo, the full url of `tabeview.css` is http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/tabview/assets/skins/sam/tabview.css. you can see there is a image called `sprite.png` is used in that `tabview.css` file, but it was not loaded. the other plain html file http://www.ceshi.anpingsiwang.info/plain.html is totally fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<body>` element is missing the `class` attribute. Just change

```
<body>
```

to

```
<body class="yui3-skin-sam">
```

and you're golden <sub><sup>(and I'm off to sleep)</sup></sub>.

---

***Edit* [demo demo demo!](http://jsbin.com/ocoyu4)**

Comment: man, you saved my life! thanks so much! now i see the importance to give test pages.